# How to highlight calls to object methods and user-created functions? (SublimeText, python)

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I tried using both Python3/PythonImproved .tmLanguage syntaxes, but neither does this for some reason. Are those actually supposed to be the same color as variables in most editors?

Here's a screenshot of some random function:

[image: function calls are not highlighed]

And here's how I want it to look like:

[image: function calls are highlighed]

To sum it up I just want everything called with parentheses like function() or an object.method() to be highlighted.

Comment: Have you tried looking into how SublimeText styles are defined, which hooks are available for formatting, etc.? None of the editors I have installed here (Atom, IDLE, PyCharm and VS2013+PTVS) highlight like that, nor do GitHub or SO, likely for the reasons outlined below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  yeah, ended up finding an extension that tells current scope at the cursor position and then created a rule in the theme file. Pretty sure it's not how I should've done it, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of Python Improved. Sublime's default Monokai theme lacks the ability to highlight many of the scopes in PI (as well as a bunch of other languages - it's quite bare-bones). One of my other projects, the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), contains rules for all of PI's new scopes, as well as scopes for a number of other languages, both built-in and third-party from Package Control. If you don't like the colors, I've tried to keep [`Neon.tmTheme`](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/blob/master/Neon.tmTheme) pretty organized, so you should be able to adapt the rules as you wish. If you have any questions or problems, feel free to submit an issue for [`Python Improved`](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved/issues) or [`Neon`](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues).

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is intended. In Python all variables you declare are bindings to objects. This means if you declare a variable `varA = 1` then the object `1` will be created and the name `varA` will be bound to this object. When you declare next `varB = 1` then `varB` will be bound to the same object as `varA`. This you can check with the built-in function `id` which returns the id of the object the variable is bound to: `id(varA) == id(varB)  # True`.

The same is for functions and instance methods. If you declare a function

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

then an object will be created which represents that function. At the same time the name `foo` is bound to that object. Declaring `bar = foo` will allow for a call of the previously created function object through bar: `bar()` will produce the same output as `foo()` (and call - or better use - the exactly same object in memory).

For instance methods this is similar. Declaring a class

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'
```

will create the required objects and bind `Foo` to the class and `foo` to the instance method of that class. Declaring `Foo.bar = Foo.foo` will allow for

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.foo()
foo
>>> f.bar()
foo
>>> Foo.foo
<unbound method Foo.foo>
>>> Foo.bar
<unbound method Foo.foo>
>>> f.foo
<bound method Foo.foo of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fd68e846fc8>>
>>> f.bar
<bound method Foo.foo of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fd68e846fc8>>
```

So every 'variable' in python is in fact the binding of a name to an object and this holds for everything, including functions and instance methods. This is why they have the same (missing) syntax highlighting in most editors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though I don't really see a reason _why_ shouldn't those be colored the same way as any built-in function. 

Like, yeah, everything is an object and a variable, but does it help the readability to implicitly not highlight those?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would like to highlight instance methods but not instance variables? I guess that's pretty difficult as SublimeText would need to be able to introspect all classes you import (e.g. from compiled modules) in order to see whether in `foo.bar()` `bar` is an instance method or simply a function that you added as an instance variable to that object. Even if this kind of introspection was possible I think in most cases `bar` will be an instance method and thus additional highlighting would unnecessarily mess up the appearance of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I used [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) to find out the scope of those calls and they are the same function-call.generic.python calls that are actually differentiated from object instances/variables in [PythonImproved](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved) .tmLanguage, though not a single theme file did anything with this scope.

So I added this rule to my color scheme file (.tmTheme):

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>generic function call</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>meta.function-call.generic.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#66D9EF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```