# Atom Python: Functions not recognised

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor, linter

I'm using Atom as my editor and I'm currently working with python.

I have installed the packages:
autocomplete-python and language-python

For some reason, functions are not marked properly.
Any idea how to turn that on?[image]

Comment: What are you expecting? Syntax highlight is usually used on function definition, not for function call.

Comment: I was expecting to have syntax highlighting for function call. In all other languages atom highlights the function calls too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all parsers and syntax color schemes will do that, and from what I know it is the case most of the time for Python syntax highlight.

But it seems that [Neon](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) highlight color scheme is able to do that for Sublime, and it is [being ported for Atom](https://atom.io/themes/neon-color-scheme), so it may be doing it in the future.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590556/how-to-highlight-calls-to-object-methods-and-user-created-functions-sublimetex) about Sublime's version of `neon` may help.

Also, it seems that the standard `language-python` package [may be limited](https://github.com/atom/language-python/issues/109) for this purpose and could be replaced by [MagicPython](https://atom.io/packages/magicpython) package.

Anyway, the feature you desire does not seem to be available at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your holistic answer! That's very unfortunate. I hope this changes in the future!